# Probability greater than mean

Tags: probability, distributions, normal-distribution

What is the probability of a value to be greater than the mean plus three times the standard deviation (assuming a normal distribution)? What is this probability for an arbitrary distribution?

Comment: Please check https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info and add a `[self-study]` tag.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality

Comment: The first question (about the normal) sounds like it may be for a class exercise. How does the issue arise? In the case of an arbitrary distribution the proportion can be anything between 0 and 1/9. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality. There are many questions on site about it.

Answer (score 4):

Compute $1 - F(μ + 3σ)$, where $F$ is the cumulative distribution function, $μ$ the mean, and $σ$ the standard deviation. When the distribution is normal, this comes out to .00135.

Answer (score 4):

For an arbitrary distribution the one-tailed Chebyshev inequality is $$P\left[ X \geq \mu + k \sigma \right] \leq \frac{1}{k^2+1} \ .$$

So for $3 \sigma,$ the probability is less than or equal to $1 \over 10 .$